# Dash table: Wrap text when dbc.Card too small

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have create a Dash table with my changelog and put this table on a dbc.Card:
This is the function for generating the table:

```
def getChangelogContent(self):
    self.dfLog['Date_Formatted'] = pd.to_datetime(self.dfLog['Date'],utc=True).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    ChangeTableData = dash_table.DataTable(
                                            id='changeTable',
                                            columns=[{"name": 'Date', "id": 'Date_Formatted'},
                                                     {"name": 'Version', "id": 'Version'},
                                                     {"name": 'Changes', "id": 'Changes'}],
                                            #data=self.dfLog.to_dict('records'),
                                            data=self.dfLog.to_dict("records"),
                                            style_table={
                                                    'padding':'20px',
                                                    'width': '100%',
                                                    'minWidth': '100%',
                                                    },
                                            style_data={'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                                                    'overflow': 'hidden',
                                                    'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',},
                                            style_cell={
                                                    'height':'auto',    
                                                    'backgroundColor': '#32383e',
                                                    'color': "#aaaaaa",
                                                    'textAlign': 'left',
                                                    'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                                                    'overflow': 'hidden',
                                                    'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',},
                                            style_header={
                                                    'backgroundColor': '#3A3F44',
                                                    'color': "white",
                                                    'fontWeight': 'bold'},
                                            editable=True

    )

    return ChangeTableData
```

and this is the placement on the dbc.Card:

```
tab_Changelog = dbc.Card(dbc.CardBody([html.H4("Changelog"),
                                     ChangelogManager.getChangelogContent()]))
```

I tried a log to automatically wrap the text, if the window and so the card is too small. But everything I tried, didn't work.
Any ideas, what I am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: You are looking for a solution for wrapping the text inside the cells of `dash_table.DataTable`, right? Or only when the card is so small?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, you should include `'whiteSpace': 'normal'` to the `dash_table.DataTable` to automatically wrap the text inside the cells.

**Code:**

```
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html


data_election = OrderedDict(
    [
        (
            "Date",
            [
                "July 12th, 2013 - July 25th, 2013",
                "July 12th, 2013 - August 25th, 2013",
                "July 12th, 2014 - August 25th, 2014",
            ],
        ),
        (
            "Election Polling Organization",
            ["The New York Times", "Pew Research", "The Washington Post"],
        ),
        ("Rep", [1, -20, 3.512]),
        ("Dem", [10, 20, 30]),
        ("Ind", [2, 10924, 3912]),
        (
            "Region",
            [
                "Northern New York State to the Southern Appalachian Mountains",
                "Canada",
                "Southern Vermont",
            ],
        ),
    ]
)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_election)

app = Dash(__name__)

table = dash_table.DataTable(
                              style_table={
                                      'padding':'20px',
                                      'width': '100%',
                                      'minWidth': '100%',
                                      },
                              style_data={'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                                      'overflow': 'hidden',
                                      'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',},
                              style_cell={
                                      'height':'auto',    
                                      'backgroundColor': '#32383e',
                                      'color': "#aaaaaa",
                                      'textAlign': 'left',
                                      'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                                      'overflow': 'hidden',
                                      'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',},
                              style_header={
                                      'backgroundColor': '#3A3F44',
                                      'color': "white",
                                      'fontWeight': 'bold'},
                                        editable=True,
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns]
)


app.layout = dbc.Card(dbc.CardBody([html.H4("Changelog"),
                                     table
                                   ],  style={"width": "5rem"}))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

**Output**

[image]